# actionscript 3.0 create color animation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, colors

Is there a simple way to animate the color of an object using actionscript in Flash?
I found a simple way in Flex,it uses the spark.effects.AnimateColor class.
I try to find something similar to Flash,is there a way or a library that i can use,
or can i somehow use the Flex libraries?
Here is the code that i found:

```
import spark.effects.AnimateColor;

var animation:AnimateColor = new AnimateColor(this);
animation.duration = 400; // milliseconds
animation.colorFrom = 0xFFCC00;
animation.colorTo = 0xaaff00;
animation.colorPropertyName = "color";

animation.stop();
animation.play();
```

Comment: This is the answer.First of all download and set the greenshock tweenlite or max `import com.greensock.TweenLite;
TweenLite.to(mc, 2, {tint: 0x0099CC});`

Comment: Actually only TweenMax works.So `import com.greensock.*;
TweenMax.to(mc, 2, {tint: 0x0099CC});`

Comment: I realized that is not exactly coloring,it adds tint but it does the sometimes the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do this using the free [GreenSock Tween libraries](http://www.greensock.com/v11/).  You'll have to look at the docs for sure.  I've only used it for X and Y tweens, but I thought colors and/or alphas were possible too.

Comment: Do i have to pay for this libraries?

Comment: No; as I stated in my post, they are free.  Be sure to read the license, though, to make sure it is allowable for your use case.

Comment: Can i ask you another thing.Is there a way to use Flex libraries in Flash?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it is overbearingly complicated.  You need to manually instantiate the framework classes, such as SystemManager.  If you Google around, there has been some experimentation around that.

Comment: Ok thanks i looked at GreenSock and is pretty much easy to do a color animation and a bunch of things such as drop filters!Great.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If this suitably answers your question; be sure to mark it as such.